# My 'for loop' inside another 'for loop' is not working

Tags: java, eclipse, for-loop, nested-loops

```
for (int i=0; i<Intlength; i++){ 
    int intPosition; 
    intPosition=strAlphabet.indexOf(strMessage.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(intPosition); 
    System.out.println("BREAK"); 
    for (int k=0; k<Intlength2; k++){ 
       int intPosition2; 
       intPosition2=strAlphabet.indexOf(strKeyword.charAt(k));
       System.out.println(intPosition2);                
       System.out.println("BREAK-------------"); 
    }
}
```

i will ask the user to type in two words. one is a message and one is a keyword.

the first loop above will check that if i
will add 1, and print out the first letters position number. for example if the message was "red". i would first want it to output the position number of "r" which is 17. then it mmust move to the second loop, and do the exact same for the keyword. for example if the keyword was "cat" i would want it to print the first letter position of the first letter in this case "c" has the position value of 2. in this way i want the output to be as such:

- first letter position of message
- first letter position of keyword
- second letter position of message
- second letter position of keyword

etc.

therefore sticking to the message "red" and the keyword "cat" i would want the output as such:

```
17
2
4
0
3
19
```

i have added in break texts to distinguish what was happening to my coding and this was the result.

```
Please give me a message:
red
Thank you! Now please give me a keyword:
cat
17
BREAK
2
BREAK-------------
0
BREAK-------------
19
BREAK-------------
4
BREAK
2
BREAK-------------
0
BREAK-------------
19
BREAK-------------
3
BREAK
2
BREAK-------------
0
BREAK-------------
19
BREAK-------------
```

as you can see it putputs the first letter position of the message, then all three positions of the keyword, and goes onto the second position letter of the message then again outputting all three position values of the keyword.
how do i fix this to get the output i want, i am sure that i am not writing the forloop correctly.

Comment: If you want 1 letter from each source you only need **one**  loop

Comment: Can you add the complete code in your `for` loops? Both your for loops are not closed.

Comment: Please fix your example code, first. It is missing trailing brackets and the indentation is way off.

Answer (score 5):

What you've got are nested for loops to make it do what you suggested they just need to be one after the other, not nested inside each other. When you put the second for loop inside the first what you're telling it to do is print each letter in the keyword for every letter in the message.

What you want is a loop like this (It's unclear what you want it to do if one string is longer than the other, I'm assuming you want it to stop with the shorter string but you can change that.)

```
if(strMessage.length > keyword.length){
    intLength = keyword.length;
} else {
    intLength = strMessage.length;
}

for (int i=0; i<intLength; i++){ 
    //Print the position of the i'th letter of the message
    int intPosition; 
    intPosition=strAlphabet.indexOf(strMessage.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(intPosition); 

    //Print the position of the i'th letter of the keyword
    int intPosition2; 
    intPosition2=strAlphabet.indexOf(strKeyword.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(intPosition2); 

}
```

Comment: the second part, you declared the letter k, however this has not been put above and therefore the letter k comes invalid

Answer (score 3):

When you nest loops, the inner one is executed from start to end for each iteration of the outer loop.

You probably need something like that (note that there's only one loop):

```
for (int i=0; i < Math.max(strMessage.length, keyword.length); i++){ 
     if (i < strMessage.length) {
         System.out.println(strAlphabet.indexOf(strMessage.charAt(i)));
     } else {
         // To be defined
     }
     if (i < strKeyword.length) {
         System.out.println(strAlphabet.indexOf(strKeyword.charAt(i)));
     } else {
         // To be defined
     }
}
```

(NB: not tested, not compiled)

Answer (score 1):

If you break your requirement, you will get to know that you have straight forward functionality of taking a character at a given index from your both the string.

So you only need **single for loop**. Inside that you can take character from first string and then from second string.

**Note:** You need to take care of length of both the strings. Depending on it you can fetch the character from it.

Answer (score 1):

Another Approach without IF else block

```
 for (int i=0; i<Math.max(strMessage.length, keyword.length);i++){ 
  int intPosition; 
  try{
   intPosition=strAlphabet.indexOf(strMessage.charAt(i));
   System.out.println(intPosition); 
  }catch(Exception e){
  }

  try{
   intPosition=strAlphabet.indexOf(strKeyword.charAt(i));
   System.out.println(intPosition); 
  }catch(Exception e){
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String strAlphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUWXYZ";
    String strMessage="red".toUpperCase();
    String strKeyword="cat".toUpperCase();
    int Intlength=strMessage.length();
    int Intlength2=strKeyword.length();
    for (int i=0; (i<Intlength) || (i<Intlength2); i++){ 
         int intPosition=strAlphabet.indexOf(strMessage.charAt(i)); 
         System.out.println(intPosition); 
         int intPosition2=strAlphabet.indexOf(strKeyword.charAt(i)); 
          System.out.println(intPosition2); 
   }
```

1) Make the comparison case-insensitive. Don't be sure that user will take care of case while typing words.
2) Ensure the expected behavior in case message length is shorter than keyword or vice versa.